# Не получается произвести к запрос базе

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

Значит проблемы такие. Я учусь делать запросы к базе на работающем проекте и суть мне надо получить из одной таблицы id постов которые имеют отношение ко 2 категории, и в последствии вывести из другой таблицы все полученные посты по id.

Вроде делал по советам с форумов и в какой то момент даже работало, но перестало. Помогите понять где ошибка в составлении запроса... или возможно в выводе...
Ошибок код не выдает.

[image: Таблица 1]

[image: Таблица 2]

```
{php}
    mysql_connect("localhost", "******_sql", "*******") or
        die("Ошибка соединения: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("cx48204_sql");

    $jquery = 'SELECT id_smart_blog_post FROM ps_smart_blog_post WHERE id_category = 2';
    $jq = mysql_query($jquery);           
    while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($jq, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
             $qquery = " SELECT * FROM ps_smart_blog_post_lang WHERE id_smart_blog_post = '$roww["id_smart_blog_post"]'";
             $rresult = mysql_query($qquery) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());
             $rrow = mysql_fetch_array($rresult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
             printf ("<a href='%s'><p>%s</p></a> <p>%s</p>", $rrow["link_rewrite"], $rrow["meta_title"], $rrow["short_description"]);
    }
    {/php}
```

Comment: Добавьте описание структуры таблиц

Comment: Добавил описание

Comment: что должно происходить при выполнении этого скрипта и что происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Код заработал.
Результат работы: На cms Prestashop выводит описание новости в любую часть сайта из модуля SmartBlog.

```
{php}

mysql_connect("localhost", "******_sql", "******") or die("Ошибка соединения: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("cx48204_sql");

$jquery = "SELECT id_smart_blog_post FROM ps_smart_blog_post WHERE id_category = '2'";
$jq = mysql_query($jquery);
while ($roww = mysql_fetch_array($jq, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
         $qquery = 'SELECT * FROM ps_smart_blog_post_lang WHERE id_smart_blog_post = ';
         $qquery .= $roww["id_smart_blog_post"];
         $rresult = mysql_query($qquery) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());
         $rrow = mysql_fetch_array($rresult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
         printf ("<a href='%s'><p>%s</p></a> <p>%s</p>", $rrow["link_rewrite"], $rrow["meta_title"], $rrow["short_description"]);
}
{/php}
```

Comment: добавьте в ответ описание того, как удалось решить проблему и в чём была ошибка, в противном случае и вопрос, и ответ на него следовало бы удалить по причине их бесполезности

Comment: Можно удалить, подскажите как это сделать.